# How to display Linkedin Share in small window

Tags: html, share, linkedin-api

I want to display LinkedIn popup in a small new window, but the share popup keeps opening as a new full screen tab.

This is the piece of HTML I'm using:

```
    <div class="share-block">
        <a 
            href="#" 
            onclick="window.open('http://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url=' + encodeURIComponent(document.URL) + '&title=Excellent review on my website reviews', '_blank, width=500, height=500, resizable=yes, scrollbars=yes'); return false;"
        ><i class="fa fa-fw fa-linkedin"></i> LinkedIn</a>
    </div>
```

I'm using the same code for Facebook and Twitter which opens up the popup in a new small window as it should. This is the Twitter HTML for example:

```
    <div class="share-block">
        <a 
            href="#" 
            onclick="window.open('https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=Excellent review on my website:%20'  + encodeURIComponent(document.URL), '', '_blank, width=500, height=500, resizable=yes, scrollbars=yes'); return false;"
        ><i class="fa fa-fw fa-twitter"></i> Twitter</a>
    </div>
```

I can't figure out why doesn't it work with LinkedIn. This is what I want to achieve
[image]

How to display LinkedIn share in new window like shown on the image?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second argument in the `window.open` is for `title`. You missed that in your linked in popup. So that it treat as all the `_blank, width=500.....` everything as title. That is the reason it is not following any property `width` and `height` and etc. Add that empty string as the second parameter `''`.

[**Fiddle DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/zfg8cf1a/3/)

Comment: Yes, this was my mistake. Thanks for pointing this out. Now it's working as it should.

Answer (score 1):

The options for the `window.open` are in the third parameter instead of in the second, where they should be.